# Subset a dataframe in R shiny using the textInput option

Tags: r

I am trying to subset a `data.frame` in Rshiny using `textInput()`. However, the input when used in subset function does not work.

## beginning of shiny app

```
    library(shiny)
ui<-fluidPage(sidebarPanel(fileInput("file","Upload your CSV",multiple=F),
                           tags$hr(),
                           h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
                           checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = FALSE),
                           checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
                           radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', 
                                        choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''),

# textinput code
    textInput("subdef", "Define subset", placeholder="TRUE")
    actionButton("click","Submit")
                           
),
mainPanel(tableOutput("dataframe")),position=c("left","right"),fluid=TRUE
)

# subsetting using the input
server<-function(input,output){

  data<-reactive({
    file1<-input$f
    if(is.null(file1)){return()}
    read.table(file=file1$datapath,sep=input$sep,header=input$header,stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
  })
f <- eventReactive(input$click, {
subset(data(),eval(parse(text=input$subdef)))
})
output$dataframe<-renderTable({
    if(is.null(f())){return()}
    f()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

> Error message object not found

Comment: Can you post full reproducible code please

Comment: have you tried using `paste0(input$subdef)` ?

Comment: yes, even paste0 does not work.. the error is subset should be logical

Comment: I tried your code with a different dataset  `airquality`from R and your code works fine with that so the problem is not with the `eval(parse(` but maybe with your input or the dataset you are using

Comment: the problem could be with `file1<-input$f` this should be `file1<-input$file`

Comment: Thank  you so much for your help Bertil !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Bertil for identifying the problem.

Issue was resolved after changing `file1<-input$f` to `file1<-input$file`